# Selenium web console not showing active sessions when run inside docker container

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I've been running a standalone chrome selenium server in AWS for a while, and am used to seeing the active browser sessions listed in the web console (located at `<selenium_host>:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html`) where I can see screenshots, kill sessions and more.

I recently migrated over to running the standalone selenium server inside a docker container and noticed that the web console is still visible but all the buttons are disabled and no sessions appear even when active browser sessions are running.[image]

There are no issues with the selenium functionality itself, I just would like to be able to view the active sessions and cannot figure out how to fix this.

Comment: How are you running the new system? Commands please